# Is it possible to store .exe or .scr files in sqlserver database using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing an asp.net 3.5 website , I need to store some screensaver files `.scr` on the host machine , I wonder if there is a way to store `.scr` or `.exe` files in sqlserver database and retreive them  ? any helps whould be appriciated .

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible (save it as a binary datatype). Why can't you you store them as files on the file-system though?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx explains it.

Comment: @RB I can save them as file system , but I want to save them in databasae ,because I want to save them on the host via a website and READ them via another website ! so I thought It would be easier to store them in a single database and read them from the same database

Comment: @RB can you guid me with some code example how to save and read th.exe or .scr file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store them as BLOB (Binary Large Object) and store the file stream, which basically is a byte array. Normally the file is stored on a server and the database only holds the file path and name. You will have to make space for a BLOB data type in your database in SQL server will allow images of 8000 bytes:
BLOBData varBinary(8000)

```
// Using DataTable as a mockup database.
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("file name");
table.Columns.Add("data");

// Read data from file.
byte[] stream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("th.exe");
// Add the file to the db, don't know how you add data to your database.
table.Rows.Add("th.exe", stream);
// Create a filestream that will write data to disk (in a file).
System.IO.FileStream save = new System.IO.FileStream((string)table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0], System.IO.FileMode.Create);
// Retrieve the data from the database, don't know how you do this with your database.
byte[] data = (byte[])table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
// Write data to the file on disk.
save.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: thx , could you add some comments on your code please ? which part is for saving the fileupload file to db and which part is for retrieveing thee file and sending to users browser for downloading the file ? thanks a lot for your answear .

Comment: thank you , in the writing file part of your code , how do you specify the file extension ? for axample .exe or .scr ?

Comment: The filetype has no effect on how you write the file. It just allows Windows to start a default program to open the file when you click on it. You can use whatever file extension you want or no extension at all. But if you are storing images I'd use the file format they are constructed with, so .png or .jpg.

Answer (score 2):

Though, you can store it as BLOB, performance could be a concern if the file size is bigger.

Alternatively, you can use Filestream Storage which is implemented as a varbinary(max) column in which the data is stored as BLOBs in the file system. The sizes of the BLOBs are limited only by the volume size of the file system. The standard varbinary(max) limitation of 2-GB file sizes does not apply to BLOBs that are stored in the file system.

For more details check msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

cheers